# Spark Job with Kafka on Kubernetes

Tags: java, apache-spark, kubernetes, apache-kafka

We have a Spark Java application which reads from database and publishes messages on Kafka. When we execute the job locally on windows command line with following arguments it is working as expected :

```
bin/spark-submit -class com.data.ingestion.DataIngestion --jars  local:///opt/spark/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0.jar local:///opt/spark/jars/data-ingestion-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0 --class com.data.ingestion.DataIngestion data-ingestion-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Similarly, when try to run the command using k8s master

```
bin/spark-submit --master k8s://https://172.16.3.105:8443 --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=localhost:5000/spark-example:0.2 --class com.data.ingestion.DataIngestion --jars  local:///opt/spark/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0.jar local:///opt/spark/jars/data-ingestion-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

It gives following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: 
org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider 
org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider could not be instantiated
```

Comment: What database are you using? Sounds like you could use Debezium instead

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error, it would indicate at least one node in the cluster does not have `/opt/spark/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0.jar`

I suggest you create an uber jar that includes this Kafka Structured Streaming package or use `--packages` rather than local files in addition to setup a solution like Rook or MinIO to have a shared filesystem within k8s/spark

Answer (score 0):

Seems Scala version and Spark Kafka version were not aligned.